# The box plot is not displaying properly

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite

I am trying to create box plot but graph is not getting rendered and showing blank graph.
lower_Box and upper_Box are undefined, please suggest
[(vega editor link)](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABKXU6oSQYYBMAEUNM2AD0M5BbTIYgw2AdxqyyQwQ4ZRokWQUg-0jw5SCkZ39DejhDAFUAZRc2HAZBJB05Q1CITE0mBkLZQzYAM0MkMlSydTYGPEMkqwAGXspFED9lejQARl7upXgaMiw0AGZepWUClFRQYgsGNTQAbVAAFThHTAB9ACEADVOABTdMNAAOMQBObvHKKyslfWxyyrgaBAAFkaMofGoHj8-jQKpg4KMgaDwZDDAAKAASADV9ABhAg3DIASgGBzogkB6Du4TOACVyLoBso2FBTlA2rIHqh5uMrABfBSHY5nK63e5jeZWF4ANlG0LKsIBSLBENKA1+CrhCKBADk2KZ4EhSujsXiCcTSeTKSBqZzTvTaHImSy2RyuQAWHoCoUnC7XO7uJ4Adnl-3hypRatDivhiPQeoNqo8mJx+MJJKUZMwFKBtrpDKdyxd7IYnLG3pAR19ooDXOlj3Go2l0a1EaT6phWrjIAA8gBRYGGABkhgAMhlLdnrXn7QX5EXWSWy6geu8K1WRf7xahRrv3UGQyANWHrcj2y2Ad2Mm16CbU+aM5Wrbn8naHYyF67S1yrKMxOvhT9MVAx3R4pXmC9w3QM9IQ7TVLyBa9KkNY0UzNdNJxzKlX3zR15xUYs3TGIMAOrLcQOlaV5jESDTxVWDaKvG8YCTNDcUMB9MOnHDZzw51FyI1B-0FStAJrbc3keWjdX1FIjShI9OwQ6D6NQ000wtTNn2wmleI-AiBO-NB3VIzdgK5Hkemk+NZJQhTjxjbUbINQw+3kriX1099CwMr9l2lUygNrBZZWld1rJABM5KjRT4NjGSDTgeS73QzSnynTy3znfi-K5XlAvEkD3Xdbpm1ik8Eui+ylPi9B+0HEdxw8nSsr4z8lzy4SfTM4LuTEeYyoc1tnKquCTyY5CkrU+8MK0jKWtw-TmUM5d+REjcgu3UZFgbKTyscxDmLGxzu1xcIkBWQx1Nc9y5qwm0eO8-DltysZunmAryLyqjuho-bhpAJCRkYoEADE3E0FZmoerzsvawS-0+8yQseT0IqBmBjq7IFR30A59GBaGZyenKOrGNbus2kCXm290BvRo6QZUyNk3Uzi7u42G2t8smV3eLrRLI5Gd3GeZDyGpV0AxrHlMi2ybpirN7uJuGecExYkd68Z3TER4ZReBnkJl2q5cS5K2PZ9Llce1WXt50ZiqDF5Ne3X8XnmYrDeB-7ZailjUQt2arc51qlsIozuSsEj1rEr60CsHlRij8KfagwHGdTpzewHYcxwnDnMsWny7cE6VdejynCq5J39xeEqvcxpn0+QlKNMfJWQ6L57w+XB2y4+mOhd6sQE7+iW0+lpuMamhSO8LvTi576uXZAoMwt1xYG+NrPp-Ntmg7nhaF+7la8rXg8V7y0ZUZ6MeautSfM4m+hWOuy3D5h0PF9Pt6PcvtAxBBiWJnIEAB1BiT82wB33mlD+KtuYlwjttf+O5uhBk9iA9A4CYrjyzn7Gerd37aU-l3Umgko4oKsNKGU70IrYOqnFPBtkkyEIPsQ+BYcf6oBKhTQWPVtxixeI8IBdCIG4O7PVXOTUC5HxJvDCOwiB6Vzjtw36OtRE4Pvs-GArDYHsJtggpeaAL6D34avEecpMEgHodvbRBDA56PmiQ4+ZCI5fEof1ZOKdcFgLEVow6yFX6pg4mwpxHDv6vW5HTEyABdAUIBkDqAANZoFAJgAAnjga0DhHCuEDEoYUcBe6UGEiAIp7JQgBFSSAdJ1Tag0DgIIZQQIjilAuI4ZGSgMlZKBAARwYDSOgBQaCkAGNACwlJQAAC84CtDQLUCwEA4DxJ0PNWQeRBDxMcHUhpTSgQ+K6Zk60sg2AIH8BYEAfJ4nslkPUsgqSrlAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field is spelt incorrectly. Try

> "field": "Text_BX_Plot",

[image]